# How to insert or on duplicate update a set of rows with different values

Tags: php, mysql

I have an array in php

```
[
    0 =>[
        "pid" => 22,
        "uid" => 1,
        "count" => 4
    ],
    1 =>[
        "pid" => 11,
        "uid" => 12,
        "count" => 5
    ],
    2 =>[
        "pid" => 5,
        "uid" => 1,
        "count" => 1
    ],
    3 =>[
        "pid" => 5,
        "uid" => 12,
        "count" => 7
    ]
]

table
pid | uid | count
```

what i want to do is to insert the record if pid and uid is not preset else update count by adding with array value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using query:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table_users (pid, uid, count) VALUES ";
foreach($array as $arr){
     $sql .= "(".$arr['pid'].", ".$arr['uid'].", ".$arr['count']."),";
}

$sql = substr($sql, 0, -1);    // this statement will remove last comma which is added during foreach loop

$sql .= " ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count=VALUES(count)";
```

This query will automatically checks if pid-uid pair exists in table, then update count else insert record. But make sure, pid and uid should be set as unqiue in table, otherwise this query will not work.

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering, can you explain the duplicate key part, the condition to check is the pair of uid and pid only

Comment: Yes, `ON DUPLICATE KEY` will check on database table if pid and uid combination already exists in table or not. If exists, then it will update value of `count` column. For duplicate key check by database table, you should make pid, uid column as unique in table by executing query `ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME ADD CONSTRAINT constr_ID UNIQUE (pid, uid)` if not set unique

Comment: You mentioned you want to check for pid-uid pair. If it was just sample, and actual columns are different from sample given in question, then you can add more columns check in database table for unique constraint and also `duplicate key update` statement will update only rest of the columns which are not under unique key constraint columns

Comment: thank you for the replies, in this case i can alter the table.
But what if there is already an id field which is primary?

Comment: id field is primary, primary is by-default unique. But sometimes, requirement arises when you want to make other columns to be unique, that columns may not be primary, but they may be unique. Like, suppose we have users table (id, name, email, company_id, address, phone). id is primary. Sometimes, requirement arises that (email, company_id) should be unique, means one company_id cannot have duplicate email. Same is the case of yours.

Comment: There is no need to do with id column, means no need to alter anything for id, id is basically we used for easy retrieval. Other columns can be unique. Other columns to make unique is normally for our requirements or project requirements.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, let me get more info on contraints :)

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($yourarrayname as $row)
{
$uid=$row->uid;
$pid=$row->pid;

$result=mysqli_query($connection,"select * from your_table where uid='$uid' and pid='$pid'");

if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
{
 //update query here
}
else
{
//insert query here
}
}
```

Comment: i am doing this way now, number of queries will be equal to the size of the array right? i want to reduce the queries

Comment: @Creatix: Yes, with this approach, number of queries will actually be double of array size. With this approach, first select query is executing and then if exists/not-exists, accordingly insert or update query is executing inside loop.